# Django: is it safe to include secret data in the context dict used to render a template in a view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

Is data that is included in the context dict passed to the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function but is not called in the template accessible to the user or their browser?
Is it ok to just pass a `QuerySet` to the template even when some of the fields of the models must be kept secret from the user?

I would appreciate a reference to the official Django documentation or any other reliable sources confirming this is safe, if anyone finds one.

**Code Example**

models.py:

```
class Riddle(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()       # show to user
    solution = models.TextField()       # very secret
```

views.py

```
def riddles_list(request):
    data = Riddle.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'riddles.html', {'riddles': data})
```

riddles.html

```
<ul>
{% for riddle in riddles %}
    <li>{{ riddle.question }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Is this safe, or does the user has a way of accessing the solution of the riddle? Is the solution now available anywhere except the Django server?

A possible approach would be to change the query to:

```
data = Riddle.objects.values('question')
```

Is this considered better code than just fetching the whole object? (for security, efficiency, readability, maintainability etc.) In the real code there are more calls like `filter` and `annotate` in the query, and the models have more fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, it is ok as long as you don't render that value to the template.

because the context is only accessible on the backend rendering engine for HTML pages.

whenever the page is rendered and sent to the browser, no one can access it.

Comment: To explain the "no one can access it": any data that is used in the templates but not output into the resulting rendered HTML or JS does not live after rendering. It's local to the render process, and after that process has finished in the server, these resources are freed. The result that is delivered to the client only contains whatever the output of the render process returned.

Answer (score 0):

> Is data that is included in the context dict passed to the render function but is not called in the template accessible to the user or their browser?

The data won't be accessible to the user in their browser as long as you don't render it. Once you render the page, what you see is the resulting string from django rendering the template.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/), specifically this paragraph under Templates.

> Django defines a standard API for loading and rendering templates regardless of the backend. Loading consists of finding the template for a given identifier and preprocessing it, usually compiling it to an in-memory representation. Rendering means interpolating the template with context data and returning the resulting string.